# create zip for more than one file and then upload it into folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want to save zip file to server for more than one file only.
first it should create zip file and then upload it to folder

```
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {

        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        string fileLocation = Server.MapPath("~/uploads/" + fileName);

        FileUpload1.SaveAs(fileLocation);



        ZipFile createZipFile = new ZipFile();

        createZipFile.AddFile(fileLocation, string.Empty);

        createZipFile.Save(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/CsharpAspNetArticles.zip"));

    }
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/

Comment: hi...my ques is if there are more than one file then first create zip and then upload that zip file to folder on upload button click

Comment: thats still not a question, try and use a word like, how, why, what or who and end the sentence with a ?.

Comment: How to upload more than one file by adding it into zip and save it in folder ??

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your "noquestion" question :) You should use IHttpHandler like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

public class ZipHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        var path = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ctx.Request.QueryString["folder"]);
        if (path == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var folderName = Path.GetFileName(path);
        if (folderName == String.Empty)
        {
            folderName = "root";
        }

        int folderOffset = ctx.Server.MapPath("~").Length;

        using (var zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(ctx.Response.OutputStream))
        {
            ctx.Response.Clear();
            ctx.Response.BufferOutput = false;
            ctx.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + folderName + ".zip");
            ctx.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip");

            zipStream.SetLevel(3);

            CompressFolder(path, zipStream, folderOffset);

            ctx.Response.Flush();
        }
    }

    private static void CompressFolder(string path, ZipOutputStream zipStream, int folderOffset)
    {
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (string filename in files)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var streamReader = File.OpenRead(filename))
                {
                    var fi = new FileInfo(filename);

                    string entryName = filename.Substring(folderOffset);
                    entryName = ZipEntry.CleanName(entryName);

                    var newEntry = new ZipEntry(entryName)
                    {
                        DateTime = fi.LastWriteTime,
                        Size = fi.Length
                    };

                    zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

                    streamReader.CopyTo(zipStream, 4096);

                    zipStream.CloseEntry();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException) { }
        }

        var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        foreach (string folder in folders)
        {
            CompressFolder(folder, zipStream, folderOffset);
        }
    }
}
```